# Css is generating a strange gap inside a container when putting inline-block elements side by side

Tags: html, css

I don't know why this gap is showing. I cannot see why this is happening I just changed the code from a studying material and doesn't work.

this is my code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Layout example</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
    <style>
     
       html,
       body {
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
       }

       header {
        width:100%;
        height:100px;
        background-color:red;
       }

       div {
        height:700px;
        margin: 0 auto;
   
       }

       aside {
        width:29.71%;
        background-color: aqua;
        height:700px;
        display: inline-block;
       }

 
       main {
        width:40%;
        height: 700px;
        background-color:pink;
        display: inline-block;

       }


       footer {
        width:100%;
        height:200px;
        background-color:blue;
       }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  
    <div class="Wrap">
       <header>

       </header>

       <div>
        <aside>

        </aside>

        <main>

        </main>

        <aside>

        </aside>

       </div>

       <footer>

       </footer>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

I don't know why that gap is showing after the aqua block.

Scenario where the author aligned the items perfectly. I couldn't find the difference though.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Layout example</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
    <style>
      html,
      body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      .Wrap {
        max-width: 1400px;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }

      .Header {
        width: 100%;
        height: 130px;
        background-color: #038c5a;
      }

      .WrapMiddle {
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 0;
      }

      .Left {
        height: 625px;
        width: 20.83%;
        background-color: #03a66a;
        display: inline-block;
      }

      .Middle {
        height: 625px;
        width: 68.75%;
        background-color: #bbbf90;
        display: inline-block;
      }

      .Right {
        height: 625px;
        width: 10.41%;
        background-color: #03a66a;
        display: inline-block;
      }

      .Footer {
        height: 200px;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #025059;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="Wrap">
      <header class="Header"></header>
      <div class="WrapMiddle">
        <aside class="Left"></aside>
        <main class="Middle"></main>
        <aside class="Right"></aside>
      </div>
      <footer class="Footer"></footer>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

There's whitespace between the elements:

```
        <aside>
          <!-- this is inside the element -->
        </aside>
          <!-- this is between the elements -->
        <main>
          <!-- this is inside the element -->
        </main>
          <!-- this is between the elements -->
        <aside>
          <!-- this is inside the element -->
        </aside>
```

The other author addressed this with `font-size: 0`, which isn't included in your version.  You can add it to the containing `div` (and adjust the widths accordingly of course).  For example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Layout example</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
    <style>
     
       html,
       body {
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
       }

       header {
        width:100%;
        height:100px;
        background-color:red;
       }

       div {
        height:700px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-size: 0; /* here */
       }

       aside {
        width:30%; /* and here */
        background-color: aqua;
        height:700px;
        display: inline-block;
       }

 
       main {
        width:40%;
        height: 700px;
        background-color:pink;
        display: inline-block;

       }


       footer {
        width:100%;
        height:200px;
        background-color:blue;
       }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  
    <div class="Wrap">
       <header>

       </header>

       <div>
        <aside>

        </aside>

        <main>

        </main>

        <aside>

        </aside>

       </div>

       <footer>

       </footer>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I expect that this layout could be done pretty easily with `display: grid`, too.  Do you have any thoughts on why to prefer one alternative over the other in this case?

Comment: @JohnBollinger: No particular reason.  I just have more experience with `display: flex` and a stronger understanding of it over `display: grid`.

Comment: I am afraid I didn't specified in my question that I wanted to stick with inline-block. I want to understand the anomalies of CSS in case I have to give maintenance on legacy websites, which I do a lot. You answer is valid. I will update my question to include some code where the author did, aligned the layout perfectly with inline-block elements. If someone could find the difference that would add to this question.

Comment: @DiegoAlves: Same issue, the original author just addressed it differently.  I've updated the answer.

Comment: It was  font-size: 0 so... I wouldn't image it. Good to know!

Answer (score 1):

As @David [already explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77379632/2402272), you have whitespace between the `<main>` element and the `<aside>` elements, and *that is significant* in an inline formatting context, such as is ordinarily established by a sequence of `inline`[`-block`] elements.

You have multiple alternatives for eliminating the gaps, including at least:

- **remove the whitespace between the elements**. This is quick and clean , but ugly and a bit harder to maintain.

  ***OR***
- **force the whitespace to be rendered with size 0**.  You can do this by setting the parent container's `font-size` to zero, which is quick but a bit dirty.  If you will be displaying text in the `<main>` and / or `<aside>` elements then you would need to compensate there.  It will also mess with dimensions expressed in `em` units.

  ***OR***
- **establish a different kind of formatting context** for the elements (`flex` or `grid`).  This is a bit more work to set up, but clean and maintainable.  It is the modern approach to handling complex layouts (and yours is complex enough for the purpose).

  ***OR***
- **position the elements involved manually**.  This is messy, a bit tricky, and harder to maintain.  I see no reason to prefer this over any of the others for your purposes.